# Applying string functions to elements that can be NaN

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with categorical data written by humans. Let's say this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["A", " A", "A ", "b", "B"]})
  name
0    A
1    A
2   A
3    b
4    B
```

I want to normalize these values by stripping spaces and uppercasing them. This works great:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x['name'].upper().strip(), axis=1)
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
```

The issue I'm having is that I also have a few `nan` values, and I effectively want those to remain as `nan`s after this transformation. But if I have this:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["A", " A", "A ", "b", "B", np.nan]})
>>> df2.apply(lambda x: x['name'].upper().strip(), axis=1)
("'float' object has no attribute 'upper'", u'occurred at index 5')
```

What I'd like is this:

```
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
5   NaN
```

I understand why this is happening (nan is a float, while others are strings), but I can't find an elegant way of writing this..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vectorized `str` operators:

```
>>> df2.name.str.strip().str.upper()
0      A
1      A
2      A
3      B
4      B
5    NaN
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. This is the cleanest way, and I didn't know about the 'vectorized string methods': http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods

Comment: Also more documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods

Answer (score 1):

you could do have an if statement in your lambda function to ensure it is a string:

```
>>> lambda x: x['name'].upper().strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x
```